# sprintf_s problems. It worked on Windows, but not on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, api

```
sprintf_s(colorBuffer, 255, "%.2X", getAlpha());
result.append(colorBuffer);
```

The error is:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'sprintf_s'

Comment: In other words, it's available for Visual C++ only. Better use standards `std::format`

Comment: In the code shown in the question, `sprintf_s` is, indeed, undeclared. As are `colorBuffer`, `getAlpha`, and `result`.

Comment: [`sprintf_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is a standard function only in C, but not in C++.

Comment: You could try adding `#define __STDC_LIB_EXT1__ 1` before including stdio.h or cstdio. I thought it was added in C11. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf I recall seeing that the standard version and Microsoft version may be different though, so you may still have issues, especially if you're using the templated Microsoft version that figures out some parameters automatically.

Comment: Make sure you read the documentation on what the function does. Its overflow behaviour surprises a lot of people when they first see it.

Comment: @heapunderrun • Nice!  I did not know that.  (I deleted my incorrect comment, since it is both wrong and may be historically misleading.)

Comment: Will the code work if I run XCode on Windows?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Is there such a thing?

Comment: @PaulSanders no, there isn't.  Xcode runs only on macOS

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf_s` is part annex K of the C11 standard, titled *"bounds-checking interfaces"*. Annex K is optional.

Annex K hasn't been successful. [N1967 Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm) stated in 1995:

> Despite more than a decade since the original proposal and nearly ten
> years since the ratification of ISO/IEC TR 24731-1:2007, and almost
> five years since the introduction of the Bounds checking interfaces
> into the C standard, no viable conforming implementations has emerged.
> The APIs continue to be controversial and requests for implementation
> continue to be rejected by implementers.

The authors even propose:

> ... that Annex K be either removed from the next
> revision of the C standard, or deprecated and then removed.

The only major compiler to implement it (or part of it) is Visual Studio. No luck with Xcode (based on clang) or gcc.